# Centos and raspberry pi 2

Tags: pi-2

I need to run centos 5ish. Is it possible to run this on a raspberry pi 2? As in does it have the power and ability. I can run centos on some old less powerful machines but they are noisy and big.

Answer (score 1):

You need a CentOS image built for ARMv7.  [This](http://seven.centos.org/2015/03/centos-linux-7-and-arm/) implies there is no such thing prior to CentOS 7, and looking further it seems that whatever images there are for 7 are not official releases, although there is at least the intention of having one.

But if you can find one, you could use it in the same manner as described [here for fedora 21](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/can-i-use-fedora-on-the-pi-2).