# Run Minecraft Pi on Fedora 21

Tags: pi-2, minecraft, fedora

I have installed Fedora 21 on my Raspberry Pi 2 using BerryBoot, and when I run minecraft-pi, I get the error: libbcm.so not found. I have already installed mesa-libEGL to fix the error: libeglv2.so not found, but I cant seem to install libbcm.

Comment: Where did you get `minecraft-pi` from?

Comment: @goldilocks from pi.minecraft.net

Comment: The odd thing is that `libbcm.so` looks like it could be something pi-specific (if 'bcm' refers to Broadcom, which it often does), but there is no such library included in Raspbian, no such library found by searching normal Debian repos, and no such library searching normal Fedora repos.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `libbcm_host.so`.  The `minecraft-pi` executable requires the following:

```
> ldd minecraft-pi 
    libGLESv2.so => /usr/lib/vc/libGLESv2.so (0x4a3b0000)
    libEGL.so => /usr/lib/vc/libEGL.so (0x4a340000)
    libbcm_host.so => /usr/lib/vc/libbcm_host.so (0x4a390000)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    libpng12.so.0 => not found
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x4b908000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4a410000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x4a2d0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4a180000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4a308000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/libX11.so.6 (0x4a788000)
    libvcos.so => /usr/lib/vc/libvcos.so (0x4a378000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x4a2f8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x4a5c8000)
    libvchiq_arm.so => /usr/lib/vc/libvchiq_arm.so (0x4a330000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x4a150000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x4a8a0000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/libXau.so.6 (0x4a928000)
```

That was checked on a pidora B+.  The library is one that is special to the pi, hence the `/usr/lib/vc` path.

It's in the github firmware repo [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/lib).  You can try getting just it specifically, then try `grep "vc/lib" /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` to see where to put it.

If that turns up nothing, create a `/opt/vc/lib` directory, owned root and set mode 755, place the library in there with the same permissions, then:

```
echo "/opt/vc/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/myrpi.conf
ldconfig
```

When you run `ldd` on `minecraft-pi` now, as up top, you should see that library linked correctly.  Please also read my note at the bottom [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27545/5538) about `/opt/vc`.

You may have further problems, but this should solve that one.