# Minecraft for the Raspberry Pi 2 cli download

Tags: lxterminal, minecraft, pidora

I was wondering what the name of minecrafts installation package was so that I could install it via terminal. I do have pidora installed on my pi.

sudo apt-get install [minecrafts download name]

Comment: Pidora is Fedora-based, if I am not mistaken, should it not be `yum` instead of `apt-get`? On Raspbian it would indeed simply be `sudo apt-get install minecraft-pi`.

Comment: You are 100% correct, thanks. I pretty confused considering the fact that I have a laptop with kali , a desktop with ubuntu, and a pi with pidora.

Comment: Related: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=80152 and https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/fedora-on-raspberry-pi if you happen to get it working, feel free to write your own answer - Q&A style! Checking the repo (minecraft site:pidora.ca) there seems to be no package.

Comment: Side note 2: Pidora is the optimized Fedora remix for the Raspberry Pi, specifically the ARMv6 architecture. The Pi2 however with its ARMv7 processor can run Fedora just fine, see [here](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2015/10/running-fedora-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/)

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33624/run-minecraft-pi-on-fedora-21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running Pidora, the package is `minecraft-pi`. So the command you need to enter would be:

```
sudo yum install minecraft-pi
```

Cheers!

Comment: why assume raspbian since he's stating to use pidora?

Comment: @pastacool sorry, just read the `sudo apt-get install [minecrafts download name]` so I assumed he was running Raspbian. I've edited my answer.