# Why will Pidora not run on my Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: sd-card, software-installation, pidora

I have one of the newer Raspberry Pi 2 B, and wish to install [Pidora](http://pidora.ca/). I have downloaded [Pidora-2014-R3](http://pidora.ca/pidora/releases/20/images/Pidora-2014-R3.zip) (the [latest?] version available from the [front page of the Pidora site](http://pidora.ca/))  and copied it on to a microSD card, and inserted it into the microSD slot on the RPi. When I power up the Pi, the green `ACT` LED lights momentarily, but then goes out and the RPi does not boot.

I have followed the [installation instructions from Pidora](http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Pidora_Installation) as well as the two guides from Raspberry Pi Documentation: [Installing Operating System Images on Mac OS -](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)  and [Installing Operating System Images using Windows](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md). I have tried both copying Pidora on to the microSD cad from both a MacBook Pro, using the various command line methods, and a Windows 7 laptop, using the [Fedora ARM Installer](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_ARM_Installer).

The microSD card is fine as I have checked it with [h2testw](http://www.heise.de/download/h2testw.html) and also, if I copy Wheezy onto it then it boots *sans problème*. I have also formatted it correctly, using [SDFormatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/).

Why will Pidora not boot on a RPi 2?

Comment: It might be possible that pidora doesn't support arm v7. Just a guess. Not sure. Try booting it on Rpi v1.

Comment: @dastaan - OK, good call. I hadn't considered that it was a processor related issue. Unfortunately I don't have a v.1 RPi.

Comment: I faced similar issue recently while burning an old `raspbian` to an SD card, and running it on Rpi 2. `ACT` blinks momentarily and then nothing. I solved it by updating kernel and raspberry bootloader by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` which booting it on Rpi 1. Once upgraded, it works fine on Rpi 2 as well as Rpi 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from the name of the image that it is an "old" image! - 2014 the Raspberry Pi 2 wasn't out and so it won't support ARMv7! ...see [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=111625) at the [Raspberry Forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=18) for more information.

- as *dastaan* pointed out (if you have a Raspberry Pi 1) you can try to upgrade the Kernel (and all other software) via
  `su`
  `yum check-update`
  `yum upgrade`
  `exit`
  and then use it in your Raspberry Pi 2.
- some users have managed to build some Pidora-images themselves as you can read [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=98424) or [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=101027)...
- or you can use one of the [official Fedora ARM images](https://arm.fedoraproject.org/).

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27544/5538