# Pidora speed on Raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pidora

Does the pi run pretty quickly when running pidora, or is it below par? Par being raspbian on the pi zero.

Comment: I would expect no significant difference between the two. Maybe you get a minor difference in boot up time. (Some people go crazy about this) But during run time? I hardly think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ghanima points out, they are almost certainly on par, since the basic components are all the same (especially now that Raspbian uses [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)).  The kernel used in both cases is exactly the same.

There is an important caveat about Pidora, however -- it is no longer being maintained.  I've been using it for a few years (Fedora is my preferred linux distro) on a B then a B+, but it has been a long, long time since `yum upgrade` said anything but "No packages marked for update."  I am planning on replacing that install with Raspbian soon. The pidora homepage is last dated 2014; I know it was created by a university research group, meaning not-really-volunteers, and when not-really-volunteers stop being paid or receiving academic credits they tend to move on.  The Pi Foundation stopped listing Pidora on its pages a while ago.

So while it does work and there is nothing wrong with it besides this, I strongly encourage you not to bother.

Comment: Shouldn't "real" Fedora run on the Pi2? No special armv6 ports, no special distro? (Well set raspberry firmware aside).

Comment: Yep: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/can-i-use-fedora-on-the-pi-2