# Installing CentOS 7 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: operating-systems, image

How do you install CentOS 7 on a Raspberry Pi? The link to download the image is [available here](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/armhfp/).

Comment: Please do not include links that click through to downloads.  The page where the download is available is fine.  I have edited for this purpose.

Comment: You can unpack that with `unxz` but since it says "Userland" I am guessing you may end up having to go this route:  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/can-i-use-fedora-on-the-pi-2 ...Depends what you actually find in the img.  If it is just one partition, then you will have to add the boot partition too.

Answer (score 8):

## Linux / OSX

1. Download the image from [here](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/armhfp/)
2. Extract the .xz file using any of the following methods

   #### Tar

   `tar xf CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1511-RaspberryPi2.img.xz`

   #### Unxz

   `unxz CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1511-RaspberryPi2.img.xz`

   #### The Unarchiver (OSX)

   Install from Mac App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12)
3. Use the disk cloning command **dd** to copy the img contents to your SD card

   `sudo dd if=‘/location/to/file.img’ of=‘dev/(sd card identifier)’`

   Notes:
   - Can take over an hour depending on SD card speed
   - You can find disk identifier using **Disk Utility** on OSX
4. When the process has completed take out the SD card, insert it into the Raspberry Pi and turn on the pi
5. Login using the username 'root' and the password 'centos'

## Windows

1. Download the image from [here](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/armhfp/)
2. Extract using .xz 7-zip
3. Install the OS onto the SD card using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3.exe)
4. Once complete, insert SD card into Raspberry Pi and turn on the Pi
5. Login using the **username** 'root' and the **password** 'centos'

If you think I've made any mistakes let me know!

Comment: the steps for windows when using the USB Installer i am not able to choose the downloaded file as it is an .img file not .iso?

Comment: Hey try another imaging software such as [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) let me know if it works and ill update the post

Comment: Win32DiskImager is what is recommended for Windows. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md

Comment: @user45039 Rename the .img file to .iso. Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Windows install above.  .img files are .iso files when decompressed. After unzipping either of the images above using 7zip just rename the file with a .iso extension and select the unlisted option from the Universal USB installer. The centOS options is for regular centOS image, not the one above.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the appropriate image, follow the instructions found on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/.

Currently [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) is recommended as "the easiest option for most users" for an SD writing tool.  It has a graphical user interface and supports multiple image types (*.img, *.iso, *.zip, etc).

Comment: Yes, with Etcher on Windows all you have to do is point it to the image file as it was downloaded from Centos mirror (no need to extract it) and SD card.