# Raspberry Pi 3 software compatibility

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, compatibility, 64-bit

Raspberry Pi 3 uses a 64-bit ARM CPU, while its predecessors used 32-bit ones.

How does this affect software compatibility?

Can **all** of the old 32 bit binary packages for Raspberry Pi 1 and 2 be properly run on it? Or have most of the Raspbian packages already been recompiled for the new architecture?

Comment: While the OS software is identical (as in the answer) the Pi3 requires different drivers and different Device Tree settings due to the changes in hardware.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While the processor in the Pi 3 is 64bit. The new chip is fully backward compatable and it uses the same 32bit OS, hence all programs will continue to work. Additional information can be found in this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43921/raspbian-moving-to-64-bit-mode/43922#43922).

Comment: How does it work with the same image file (if it does)? It has firmware, dev tree, kernel overlays and `config.txt` for both versions? For what SoC the kernel is compiled?

Comment: @Velkan If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.This is not something that can/sjould be answered in a comment.