# Running 64 bit Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit

Are there any 64-bit Ubuntu ARM images? All I can find is a 64-bit x86 image and a 32-bit ARM image, but I'd like to take advantage of the Raspberry Pi 3's 64 bit architecture. [This](https://www.linux.com/news/raspberry-pi-3-still-essentially-32-bit-sbc-now) article implies I might be out of luck. Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: All you have to do is rewrite the kernel and all modules for 64 bit. What would you achieve seeing as memory is limited to 1GByte (apart from making the code bigger)?

Comment: This question and its answers will provide some additional insight into the issue http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43921/raspbian-moving-to-64-bit-mode?rq=1

Comment: @Milliways - I have a Dragonboard410c running Linaro 64-bit ARM Linux and it does just fine with 1GB of RAM. App and data usage can increase by going 64-bits, but it doesn't have to. Aarch64 instructions are still 32-bits each and no one forces you to store data as 64-bit ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The foundation kernel has been ported by third parties to 64 Bit](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=143856&p=949451) ,
but only by breaking HW acceleration, camera
support , WiFi and Bluetooth.

Whether Canonical is interested to use this completely custom downstream kernel is an question only they themselves can answer.

Don't forget that most Raspberry Ubuntu images *don't seem to be maintained and supported by Canonical at all* , but by **community efforts**.

Of course most download pages are **not** thinking about AArch64 when they write 
"64-bit" , **even Canonicals main "64-bit" download does not work on the Pi directly**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running

```
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1012-raspi2 #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 11 10:06:55 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

right now on a Raspberry PI 4 with 4 GB of RAM.

I believe I got the image at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Ubuntu_arm64.2FAArch64 (but I did a lot of flailing around to find it). Nevertheless, the file I flashed to the SD chips was named:

```
ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img
```

and it booted. USB didn't work until I used ssh to login and add `total_mem=3072` to `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt` (there are probably smarter ways to do this). After I rebooted USB works (and thus keyboard & mouse).

Haven't figured out how to get my desktop environment installed yet...