# Partition Format

Tags: debian

I am new to Linux and RaspberryPi, but i hope someone will help me.
I have installed Raspbian on raspberryPi. But i have some specific requirements on partition file system. Unluckly i did not get any setting during installation of raspbian to manually configure the file system of partition. Now i want to change FAT16 to EXT2 but unable to do this.
Is someone know how i can do this?
Or any suggestion to install Native Debian on raspberryPi directly instead of raspbian?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming you mean the boot partition I don't believe you can as this would prevent the Pi from booting.

Comment: Why would you use native, generic arm distro over one specifically made for the pi? Is there something "missing" from raspbian compared to generic arm debian?

Answer (score 2):

> i want to change FAT16 to EXT2 but unable to do this.

You can't do that with the first partition.  Well -- you can, but if you do the card will be no good for use in a Raspberry Pi.  The [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) has some basic requirements in this context.  It doesn't have a BIOS and cannot do things like select a boot device and hand-off directly to whatever OS on whatever filesystem.  It requires the first partition on the card be FAT formatted and contain some specific files (I believe the name of the first one loaded is hardwired into the chip); those files then contain firmware used to bootstrap the GPU which actually initializes the CPU, etc. -- you'll find better explanations of this online if you are interested, but the point is, that partition has to be what it is, no matter what kind of operating system you intend to run beyond that.

Also, EXT2 is outdated.  Raspbian like other contemporary GNU/Linux distros uses EXT4 by default for the root partition.

> I have installed Raspbian on raspberryPi.

Okay, so there will be two partitions there: the first small (~60 MB) vfat boot partition, and a much larger (2 GB+) ext4 second partition that is the root filesystem for the OS.  Although the kernel is on the first partition and that partition is subsequently mounted on `/boot`, technically it isn't required for anything once the kernel has loaded -- it is kept mounted so that it can be updated normally by the OS package manager (`apt`).

> any suggestion to install Native Debian on raspberryPi directly instead of raspbian?

This depends on the model.  If it is an A/B/+/0 (i.e., ARMv6 based) model, I really recommend you do not bother.  The only Debian version which will (or might) work is `armel`, and this will probably perform worse and leave your hands tied when it comes to various bits of pi specific software, such as openGL libs for the GPU.

You'll still have to use the Pi kernel anyway. Although I believe enough stuff has been incorporated into the vanilla tree now that you can use it on an A/B/+/0, you'll have to compile that yourself and I am not sure how easy it will be to find paint-by-numbers style directions, so you better know what you are doing.

If you are using the Pi 2 or 3 (ARMv7 and v8 based), Debian's `armhf` port should work, but will require [some adaptation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27544/5538) (yes, that's about Fedora, but the exact same principles apply).  There may be some confusion here because Rasbpian uses the `armhf` suffix with packages for some (confusing) reason.  These are not the same.  Conventionally Debian uses it the same way as most other distros that have such a port, to refer to ARMv7+ based devices; the A/B/+/0 are based on the final version of ARMv6, which is almost but not quite ARMv7.

The Pi 3 is 64-bit ARMv8 based and so the [Debian Arm64 port](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Port) should work (other distros are using "aarch64" for this), but again subject to the aforementioned tweaks and custom kernel.

I **very strongly suggest** you stick with Raspbian until you get the swing of things.  *It pretty much is Debian 8,* so much so that it would be easier just to tweak the configuration and (e.g.) GUI stack to match than it would be to install generic Debian.  They even stick to the same version numbering/naming scheme (wheezy and jessie, hence the first Raspbian was actually Raspbian 7).

Comment: You may want to search around for people who've deployed Xen on the pi first (or tried to).  There is [a Debian armhf package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xen-hypervisor-4.4-armhf) but you also need a customized kernel (or two?) for that; presuming the hypervisor package includes the first kernel, it won't do you any good on the pi because a generic ARMv7 kernel won't work.  There is no armel package.