# Linux 64 on pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, linux, 64-bit

Can anyone confirm and identify an .img download for a raspberry pi that executes Linux (preferably ubuntu server) in 64 bit mode?

Answer (score 3):

I know people wanted to do this when the Pi 3 came out, so I did a bit of googling and the first thing I found was [BUILD A 64-BIT KERNEL FOR YOUR RASPBERRY PI 3](https://devsidestory.com/build-a-64-bit-kernel-for-your-raspberry-pi-3/).  It was first posted a year ago but looks to have been kept updated, and the author eventually put "an experimental 64-bit OS for the Raspberry Pi 3" up on [github](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64).  It is "based on Debian Stretch and backed by a 4.11 Linux kernel" -- that's from the 4 month old README, so it seems to be fairly current; other files in the repo have been updated more recently, so it still looks to be actively developed.

I read through some of the original post, and it refers to a "bcmrpi3" make config file for arm64 in the Foundation's kernel source, and low and behold, [it is there](http://http:/an%20experimental%2064-bit%20OS%20for%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%203.%20It%20is%20/).

If you don't want to use that OS, you could use another arm64 distro with that kernel, using [this methodology](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27545/5538) (keeping in mind the pi specific userspace libraries and apps copied in from the firmware repo will instead have to be compiled from source, if you want them).  Unfortunately, it appears there's no [official Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) for arm64 at this time (there's only a 32-bit ARM one).

Comment: +1 pi64-lite.zip from the releases section of that github project worked out of the box for me. Did `sudo apt install g++` then successfully compiled and ran aarch64 helloworld.