# Install Alpine Linux mini root filesystem distribution on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: boot, pi-zero-w, operating-systems, bootloader

I am trying to install the `mini root filesystem` distribution of Alpine Linux on my Raspberry Pi Zero W which can be downloaded for the `armhf` architecture from the official [Alpine Linux download page](https://www.alpinelinux.org/downloads/). I use this version and not the regular one for Raspberry Pis because I want to modify the image in a `chroot` environment prior to flashing it to the SD card. The approach is explained in two blog articles ([manually](https://disconnected.systems/blog/raspberry-pi-archlinuxarm-setup/) and [scripted](https://disconnected.systems/blog/custom-rpi-image-with-github-travis/)) but unrelated to the actual problem. It is enough to know that the regular Raspberry Pi image will only expand into a regular file system in memory during first boot and hence cannot be modified in advance.

The issue I am facing is that the `mini root filesystem` distribution makes use of symbolic links. These, however, are not supported on the `FAT32` file system. `FAT32` seems to be the only file system recognized by the Raspberry Pi as boot partition. If I create for instance an `ext4` formatted partition which supports symbolic links, the Raspberry Pi won't boot at all.

Other Linux distributions for the Raspberry Pi often use multiple partitions: A boot partition formatted as `FAT32` and a second one, e.g. formatted as `ext4`, which contains the actual root file system.

How would I create such a boot partition? Where would I get the files from that need to be on it in order to boot the Raspberry Pi, then load the root file system from the second partion?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're after, but to create a custom image, mimic the structure of the normal one.  One way to do that (and ensure you have all the correct stuff in the boot partition) is to start with a Raspbian image and replace the second partition: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27545/5538

Comment: Could you clarify why you can't create an extra EXT4 partition? Are you running our of space?

Comment: No problem to create an extra partition for the root file system. However, then I still don't know what to put on the `FAT32` boot partition. Apparently this is not the right use case for this Alpine flavour, I think it is more meant to be used in Docker containers and such that "borrow" the Kernel from the host operating system.