# Chromium Browser keeps crashing after update

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi 2.

While Chromium 48 did work fine, after updating to 51 it keeps crashing on start: it simply says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Is there a way to get more information about what's happening in the background? How to fix the error?

Comment: whats your GPU/CPU memory split like ? just a shot in the dark, but it could be case of memory allocation failure and/or null [pointer reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Null_pointer_dereference) leading to a seg fault. try [tweaking](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/31606/33810) to allocation ratio using `raspi-config` and seeing if the situation improves

Comment: @ShreyasMurali I'm using Ubuntu Mate. How can I find that out?

Comment: you can use `sudo nano /boot/config.txt
` to view/edit the boot configuration (one such config is the memory split ratio). have a look at [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50760/33810) answer and [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=112253) post for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstalled previous, working, version of chromium-browser - not all that straightforward...

I had to `apt-get remove ...` and `apt-get purge ...` on both `chromium-browser` and `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` because when reinstalling the version numbers must match. then `apt-get install ...` on the two of them, appending the version number (the same for both):

```
apt-get install chromium-browser=45.0.2404.101-0ubuntu1.1201
apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra=45.0.2404.101-0ubuntu1.1201
```

it seems to work again. And BTW I got available version numbers by using `apt-cache policy chromium-browser`

**Update 2:**

Seems version 45.0.2404.101-0ubuntu1.1201 has ssl certificate problems with some sites. so.... I followed the instructions on here *[dead link]* and all's well for now:

> ```
> wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb
>
> wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
>
> wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know much about Chromium but if you want to trace and find appropriate solution, this could be helpful.

"Segmentation fault" happened because the program crashed and at the same time core is dumped. By looking at its definition, it refers to printing or the copying to a more permanent medium (such as a hard disk ) the contents of random access memory ( RAM ) at one moment in time. One can think of it as a full-length "snapshot" of RAM.

To debug this, you need to enable to create core file: `ulimit -c unlimited` and check everything is set correct by `ulimit -c unlimited` and after it crashes you would see `core.<process-pid-here>` file. This is your core dumped file.

*[ ...Likely cut n' pasted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22711917/1151724 or a common source... ]*

To analyze this file, you need GDB tool and it would be already installed on your pi. you need several steps to debug this.

1- Find the directory where the corefile is generated.

2- Use ls -ltr command in the directory to find the latest generated corefile.

3- Load the corefile:
gdb binary path of corefile

4- Then you can get the information using bt (backtrace) command.

5- To print the variables use print varibale-name or p varibale-name

6- To get any help on gdb use help option or use apropos search-topic

7- Use frame frame-number to go to desired frame number.

8- Use up n and down n commands to select frame n frames up and select frame n frames down respectively.

9- To stop gdb use quit or q.

This is the how you debug core file.

Comment: This is a preposterous way for an end user to solve a problem with an application crashing.  *It is simply a complete waste of that person's time.*  What is the OP going to do, spend a few weeks studying the Chromium code base so he can come up with, test, and propose a patch -- presuming that's where the problem is?  **Debuggers are for developers.**.